# How to add path in qt .pro file via DEFINE

Tags: qt, qmake

I want to add a path to my translations folder in the .pro file, which can be accessed from C++ / QML parts as well as used inside the .pro file.

I came across the DEFINES+=  function and made it work with an example for the number PI. This define can be called from C++ using  qDebug()<

Now i have a translations folder two directorys above the .pro file which is called translations. Therefor i tried to use something like this:

```
DEFINES += "TRANSPATH=\"../../translations\""
```

But when I try to access it via qDebug i get the errors
- expected primary expression
and
- expected unqualified id before "." token

In my .pro file I want to access the TRANSPATH as well, but using it like

```
 TRANSLATIONS += \
     $$(TRANSPATH)/test_TEST.ts \
     ../../translations/de_DE.ts \
     ../../translations/zh_CN.ts
 }
```

only leads to this error:

```
  Updating '../../../../../../../test_TEST.ts'...
      Found 63 source text(s) (63 new and 0 already existing)
  Cannot create /test_TEST.ts: Zugriff verweigert  
  Updating '../../translations/de_DE.ts'...
      Found 63 source text(s) (0 new and 63 already existing)
```

I tried to find other examples online but haven´t found anything helpfull. 
In the TRANSLATIONS += part i had changed the wording to:

```
  TRANSPATH/test_TEST.ts
  {TRANSPATH}/test_TEST.ts 
  $$TRANSPATH/test_TEST.ts
  $${TRANSPATH}/test_TEST.ts
```

but nothing worked. This is the first time I´m trying to DEFINE something, maybe I´m doing it wrong? Please help

Example code / .pro file:

```
 # this file will be loaded from the main import path
  MAIN_QML_FILE = main.qml
  INCLUDEPATH += ./Plugins
  INCLUDEPATH += ./qml
  DEFINES += "PI=\"3.1415926\""
  DEFINES += "TRANSPATH=\"../../translations\""
  QT += core
  # this is only seen by the linguist tools (lupdate)
  lupdate_only{
  SOURCES = \
      ../../qml/Widgets/SomeFiles/*.qml

  TRANSLATIONS += \
      $$(TRANSPATH)/test_TEST.ts \
      ../../translations/de_DE.ts \
      ../../translations/zh_CN.ts
  }
```

TRANSPATH should lead to the same folder as the ../../translations/de_DE.ts
path does. The path would be reused from C++ for a custom QTranslator object.

Answer (score 2):

First, this error from `qmake`:

```
Cannot create /test_TEST.ts: Zugriff verweigert
```

comes from here:

```
$$(TRANSPATH)/test_TEST.ts
```

You're referencing an undefined *variable*, i.e. TRANSPATH. When you do this:

```
DEFINES += "TRANSPATH=\"../../translations\""
```

you're not defining a *variable*: you're appending a define to the compiler command line, using `-D` flag (you can check this in the compilation output pane, in creator).

So, **just have a `qmake` variable**:

```
TRANSPATH = ../../translations
```

Now you can use it elsewhere in your pro file, e.g.

```
  TRANSLATIONS += \
      $$(TRANSPATH)/test_TEST.ts \
      ../../translations/de_DE.ts \
      ../../translations/zh_CN.ts
  }
```

You can use it in `DEFINES`, too, but take care of escaping:

```
DEFINES += "TRANSPATH=\\\"$$TRANSPATH\\\""
```

In your compiler out you will find

```
-DTRANSPATH=\"..\..\translations\"
```

along with the other flags.

Now you can safely do

```
qDebug() << TRANSPATH;
```

in your source code.

Comment: Still not reaching the correct folder... but accessing from C++ works now

Updating '../../../../../../../test_TEST.ts'...
    Found 63 source text(s) (63 new and 0 already existing)

Cannot create /test_TEST.ts: Zugriff verweigert